# Why does `print -c` fail, but piping to `column` succeed to print columns?

Tags: zsh, shell-builtin

This works:

```
#!/bin/zsh

### List apps ###

arch="$(paru --query --quiet --explicit --unrequired)"
repos=( $HOME/repos/./* )
npm=( $(npm list --global --parseable) )
box="${(l:20::─:)}"

print -l "${arch}" "${box}" "${repos[@]:t}" "${box}" "${npm[@]:1:t}" | column
```

Results:

```
alsa-utils                    foot                          libva-utils                   patch                         waylock
android-tools                 fuzzel                        links                         pdfarranger                   wine-gecko
anki                          fwupd                         linux-lts                     pinta                         winetricks
aria2                         fzy                           linux-zen                     pkgconf                       wl-color-picker
auto-cpufreq                  github-cli                    lswt                          pkgstats                      wlsunset
autoconf                      gnu-netcat                    make                          polkit-gnome                  xdg-user-dirs
automake                      go                            man-db                        pulsemixer                    xorg-xeyes
base                          gocryptfs                     mdcat                         python-android-backup-tools   zip
bison                         grabc                         meld                          qutebrowser                   zram-generator
brightnessctl                 greetd                        microsoft-edge-stable-bin     ripgrep                       zsh-completions
calibre                       greetd-tuigreet               moreutils                     river                         ────────────────────
cheat                         grive                         mupdf                         rivercarro                    ansiweather
cmus                          helix                         ncdu                          rustup                        bash-script-template
cups-pdf                      httrack                       neomutt                       speedtest-cli                 cheatsheets
dragon-drop                   imv                           newsboat                      swayidle                      paru
dunst                         intel-gpu-tools               nicotine+                     system-config-printer         typewritten
edk2-shell                    intel-ucode                   noto-fonts-cjk                tealdeer                      zsh-z
efibootmgr                    inxi                          noto-fonts-emoji              timeshift                     ────────────────────
eg                            iwd                           onedrive-abraunegg            tiny-irc-client               vercel
fd                            jpegoptim                     pacman-contrib                ufw
flex                          jq                            pandoc-bin                    urlview
foliate                       kakoune                       paru                          vscode-langservers-extracted
```

But changing the last line to run `print -c` instead of piping to `column` doesn't work; it prints vertically:

```
print -c "${arch}" "${box}" "${repos[@]:t}" "${box}" "${npm[@]:1:t}"
```

Comment: And what's the output of `typeset arch box repos npm`?

Comment: The screenshot doesn't seem to match the code. We see only one $box.

Comment: What OS are you on? Does `print -r -- ${(l[20][─])}` (padded to a length of 20 characters) give a different output from `print -r -- ${(ml[20][─])}` (padded to a display width of  20 columns) on your system?

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Originally, I posted two large screenshots. It seemed that was overkill, so I removed one and cropped the other. I've now replaced the cropped screenshot with a full-sized one.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas I've edited the OP with the output of `typeset arch box repos npm`.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas I'm on Arch. The two line drawing commands produce the same output.

Comment: Your `$arch` is just one very long string instead of a list of packages. See edit to my answer.

Comment: Thanks, I'll remove my comments.  Also the output of `typeset arch` is probably needed since the answer is based on it.

Comment: @muru I don't know what the instructions for that were anymore.

Comment: See first comment above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `$arch` variable is defined as a scalar variable that contains a very long string with newline characters in it.

You want each line in that string to be passed as separate arguments to `print -c` for it to be able to print them in columns, so for `$arch` to be an array with each line as a separate element.

Getting the (non-empty) lines of some output is with `${(f)"$(cmd)"}` in `zsh` where the `f` parameter expansion flag splits on line`f`eed characters:

```
#! /bin/zsh -

 arch=( ${(f)"$(paru --query --quiet --explicit --unrequired)"} )
repos=( ~/repos/*(N:t) )
  npm=( ${${(f)"$(npm list --global --parseable)"}:t} )
  sep=${(l[20][─])}

print -rc -- $arch $sep $repos $sep $npm[2,-1]
```

If you wanted to print the lists each on their  own column, removing the need for a separator:

```
paste <(print -rC1 -- $arch) \
      <(print -rC1 -- $repos) \
      <(print -rC1 -- $npm[2,-1]) |
  expand -t 20
```

Example:

```
$ paste <(seq 10) <(seq 12) <(seq 3) | expand -t20
1                   1                   1
2                   2                   2
3                   3                   3
4                   4
5                   5
6                   6
7                   7
8                   8
9                   9
10                  10
                    11
                    12
```

Other notes:

- note the `N` qualifier for the script not to abort if there's no non-hidden file in `~/repos`
- almost any time you use `print`, you should use the `-r` option as the default without it is to do some form of backslash processing you generally don't want and use `-` or `--` to separate options from things to print. Not doing the latter can introduce command injection vulnerabilities.
- the `/./` in your code serve no purpose as far as I can see and I've removed it. If you wanted to include hidden files, you'd add the `D` glob qualifier.
- if you wanted to exclude `lib` from `$npm` without having to assume it's the first one, you'd use `${num:#lib}` instead of `$num[2,-1]` (which I much prefer to the `${num:1}` which zsh only added recently and only for compatibility with ksh93/bash).
- `print -rC1 --` is better than `print -rl --` (and a fortiori than `print -l`) to print on `1` `C`olumn in that it prints nothing instead of an empty line when given no argument so is a more canonical way to print a list, one element per line.

Comment: It's a good tip to `paste` and `expand`, but in my case I'd prefer the separators.

Comment: What's the importance of expansion to empty if no match with the `(N)` flag? Also, why not use `/./*` instead of just `/*` since filenames can begin with a hyphen?

Comment: The top script here prints a vertical list for me, without columns.

Comment: I thought `/./*` was to properly handle filenames beginning with a hyphen?

Comment: Why don't the arguments to print  (`$arch $sep $repos $sep $npm[2,-1]`) need quoting? What if they contained an unusual character or a space in their values?

Comment: In the `arch` variable assignment, why isn't the flag `${(f)` quoted?

Comment: In the `repos` variable assignment, you used a tilde instead of `$HOME`. I had read we should always use `$HOME` in scripts. Why the tilde?

Comment: @PoundHash prefixing a glob with `./` helps with filenames starting with hyphens in that the resulting words no longer start with hyphens but it's pointless with `foo/./*` as those words start with `foo`, not hyphen and `-foo/./*` would still start with hyphens. In any case, `:t` removes everything up to the last /`, so you could end up with words starting with hyphens. We guard against those by using `--` so those repos starting with hyphens are not taken as option to `print`.

Comment: zsh doesn't have that misfeature of sh/ksh/bash whereby unquoted parameter expansions undergo IFS-splitting+glob. They do still undergo empty-removal which sometimes is undesirable but not here and in any case `$(cmd)` removes trailing empty lines anyway. `$(cmd)` does undergo IFS-splitting, hence the `"$(cmd)"`. `"$array"` or `"${(f)...}"` would join the elements with the first character of $IFS like `"$*"`, `"${array[*]}"` do in ksh. We could use `"${(f@)"$(cmd)"}"` similar to `"$@"` which would preserve empty elements, but we don't want those anyway.

Comment: `~` expands to the home directory, it's what it's for. You may have read a recommendation from the 80s where `sh` was still the Bourne shell and didn't have that feature. POSIX sh has tilde expansion.